# Autocomplete with remote source

Tags: java, service, web, autocomplete

I have an application which needs to have autocomplete on it's item. I don't have those items on my side, but there is web service which I invoke to get the items. should I somehow store those items on my side (there is about 100 billion items ) or just cal that web serive for each letter client enters in the text box?

Comment: So do you start autocompleting as soon as the first character is written? How MANY suggestions you want to give ?

Comment: If you have such a huge dictionary base, then you should not suggest anything till user inputs a few characters (say 3 characters). Now you should write some server side logic which shall return only the possible matches to this entered string and use javascript libs to autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to have a good answer with this knowledge, but ideally:

- Implement it in web service an API: getSuggestions
- Call web service every keystoke

  - If that approach generate too much load on server, call it only X ms after text field change only if there was no other changes in meantime. (where e.g. X = 300 ms)

    - That way you avoid autocomplete while you typing.
- Regardless whether it will be server/client based you need some indexing (use some sophisticated [data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017808/best-data-structure-for-dictionary-implementation)) to get a decent performance. You may use `lucene` to get it for almost "free".