# Does Java have an database-like structure?

Tags: java

I've been writing a "sort and aggregate" approach to making this ~100MB data set  efficiently searchable but the code's getting a bit long.

The objects are simple classes like

```
class item {
    public int type = 1;
    public int damage = 4;
}
```

And what I've done is essentially make a class where I can say `items.type(1).damage(4).getItem();`

Does Java have any classes for turning objects into something searchable in a similar way?

I've been looking at Java Collections and Entities, where what I've written is a giant `ArrayList<Item>` and several `HashMap<Item>`

Comment: The immediate question that comes to mind: for a 100 million record data set, why don't you want to use a real, proven database? Feels like you're reinventing the wheel. There's plenty of free, open source, fairly easy to use systems. PostgreSQL happens to be my favorite at the moment, but you don't even have to use a relational DB nowadays.

Comment: [Best data structure for dictionary implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017808/best-data-structure-for-dictionary-implementation)

Comment: Wild guess, is this Minecraft-related?

Comment: @immibis Hah :P No I'm just experimenting game-design just using basic java and Graphics2D.

Comment: That should say MB, and because there's sprite data in the items, I guess in without the sprites is much less, but I can't really account for how much.

Comment: If you're really in need of something embedded that doesn't require a separate service running, there's also options like HSQL or SQLite. You'll definitely need to do some benchmarking to make sure they can handle that kind of load, though, and I would be very surprised if you didn't have to do some very heavy tuning to get it working reasonably. Even so, I'd certainly rather use a fairly well tested system like those than roll my own.

Comment: Oh, 100 MB. Still, how many rows are you talking?

Comment: Its only several hundred, less then a thousand rows easy.

Comment: That's probably more relevant than the data size; it's really not that many. Question: how is the performance using a simple linear search? This is something you should check before trying to optimize. If that's no good, what about optimizing the search for one parameter? That could potentially be done with some kind of bucket structure, which could go in a hash map (mapping parameter to bucket list). You'd just do a linear search on the bucket itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 might be fitting:

```
Item item = items.stream()
    .filter((it) -> it.type == 1)
    .filter((it) -> it.damage == 4)
    .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

P.S. In your case `.parallel()` might help with a speed gain (divide and conquer).

Comment: Oh wow, looks just like LINQ. Good to know that exists I'm checking it out right now.