# What would be a good data structure to store a dictionary(of words) to optimize the search time?

Tags: algorithm, search, fuzzy-search

Provided a list of valid words, and a search word, I want to find whether the search word is a valid word or not ALLOWING 2 typo characters.

What would be a good data structure to store a dictionary of words(assumingly it contains a million words) and algorithm to find whether the word exists in the dictionary(allowing 2 typo characters).

If no typo characters where allowed, then a Trie would be a good way to store the words but not sure if it stays the best way to store dictionary when typos are allowed. Not sure what the complexity for a backtracking algorithm(to search for a word in Trie allowing 2 typos) would be. Any idea about it?

Comment: Related (and containing answers pertinent to this question):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017808/best-data-structure-for-implementing-a-dictionary?rq=1

Comment: Also related is my answer on this one, which can quickly find good candidate words without focusing on a specific edit distance:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294915/what-algorithm-gives-suggestions-in-a-spell-checker

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout Directed Acyclic Word Graph or **DAWG**. It has more of an automata structure than a tree of graph structure. Multiple possibilities from one place may provide you with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need to also store all mistyped words I would consider to use a two-step approach for this problem.

1. Build a set containing hashes of all valid words (not including
   typos). So probably we are talking here about some 10.000 entries,
   which should still allow quite fast lookups with a binary search. If
   the hash of a word is found in the set it is typed correctly.
2. If a words hash is not found in the set the word is probably
   mistyped. So calculate a the Damerau-Levenshtein distance between
   the word and all known words to figure out what the user might have
   meant. To gain some performance here modify the DL-algorithm to
   abort calculation if the distance gets bigger than your allowed
   threshold of 2 typos.